# How can we pass array of objects as parameter to httpGet in Angular 2 and above?

Tags: javascript, angular, http-get

I have a httpGet api which returns blob data. In this api, I want to pass params like this.

```
public downloadImages(queryOptions: QueryRequest[]) {
const params = {
  QueryOptions: [
    {
      QueryType: "SystemData",
      QueryParameters: [
        "ALL"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

return this.http.get('/SystemInfo/DownloadData', { params: params, observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
```

}

Above code gives compile time error. Looks like Angular is not supporting params in this format or Am I using the wrong syntax? How can I pass params in  this format to Angular httpGet with responseType as blob?

Answer (score 0):

Create a param object and pass

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("QueryOptions", JSON.stringify([
    {
      QueryType: "SystemData",
      QueryParameters: [
        "ALL"
      ]
    }
  ]))

return this.http.get('/SystemInfo/DownloadData', { params: params, observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
```